# Sverchok: Parametric Brick Wall

Tags: sverchok

I was trying to reproduce this grasshopper [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thmjML1tyFU&t) on creating a parametric brick wall and I was able to reproduce almost everything, except the bricks rotation along the surface.

[image]
In the left side is the expected result, in the right side is what I got

I tried using the "duplicate bojects along an edge" node, but it seems that is doesn't work with multiple items in a list (it creates only the first one).

Any ideia how I could approach this?

Here is my node setup:
[image]

Thanks!

[EDIT]
Here my final setup after @nikitron answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tree instead. and developt it
https://gist.github.com/4d0867def4fb5a12f7ce5485970302fe
[image]

Comment: https://gist.github.com/e8e24c4a3f542abe0e00bb2f028f26b4

Comment: Thanks, @nikitron, It worked!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/0f1ca13e501d737ccf2a32e6f2c1b40a also import this gist - copy adress and press import from gist on panel